# porque el valor de la variable i cambia dentro de una funcion anidada

Tags: javascript

mi problema surge al usar un for y luego hacer una consulta ajax, i debe cambiar por cada ciclo, lo cual hace, pero al consultar la variable dentro de una funciona anidada, siempre da el mismo resutlado, ayuda por favor

```
$("#notas_materia").change(function(event){
n_materia=event.target.value
$("#tablanotas").show();
                    $.get("/secretaria/notas/prealumnos/"+n_periodo+"/"+n_jornada+"/"+n_modalidad+"/"+n_curso+"/"+n_seccion+"/"+n_materia+"",function(response5){
                        for(i=0; i<response5.length; i++){ //el length en este caso es 3
                    console.log(i);//muestra 1,2,3
                    $.get("/docentes/notas/"+n_periodo+"/"+n_jornada+"/"+n_modalidad+"/"+n_curso+"/"+n_seccion+"/"+n_materia+"/"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"",function(response6){
                        console.log(i);//muestra siempre 3
                                if(response6){
                                    $("#tcuerpo").append("<tr><td class='idAlumno'>"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"</td><td class='alumno'>"
                                    +response5[i]['alumnos'][0].nombres+" "+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].apellidos+"</td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_a+"'></td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_e+"'></td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_t+"'></td></tr>");
                                }else{
                                    $("#tcuerpo").append("<tr><td class='idAlumno'>"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"</td><td class='alumno'>"
                                    +response5[i]['alumnos'][0].nombres+" "+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].apellidos+"</td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td>"
                                    +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td></tr>");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
```

el controlador lo que devuelve es una consulta a db que nunca tiene cambios en la variable i

```
public function getNotas(Request $request, $n_periodo, $n_jornada, $n_modalidad, $n_curso, $n_seccion, $n_materia, $n_alumno){
 
    if($request->ajax()){
        $lasNotas=Nota::select('alumno_id','nota_a','nota_e','nota_t')
                        ->where('year',date('Y'))
                        ->where('periodo',$n_periodo)
                        ->where('jornada',$n_jornada)
                        ->where('modalidad',$n_modalidad)
                        ->where('curso',$n_curso)
                        ->where('seccion',$n_seccion)
                        ->where('materia_id',$n_materia)
                        ->where('alumno_id',$n_alumno)
                        ->first();
                    }
                    return $lasNotas;
  }
```

y mi ruta para llegar al controlador es

```
Route::get('docentes/notas/{n_periodo}/{n_jornada}/{n_modalidad}/{n_curso}/{n_seccion}/{n_materia}/{n_alumno}', 'NotaController@getNotas');
```

Comment: Mismo problema de siempre con js... el i de adentro esta en otro ambito distinto al i de afuera.... no encuentro la pregunta en el sitio que lo explica

Comment: Diria que el **for** corre por un lado mientras aún se estan ejecutando las peticiones ajax asincronas de **$.get**, de tal modo que, aunque no lo parezca, el bucle termina antes de ejecutar la primera petición asincrona $.get y por eso ya coge ese valor cuando se ejecuta.  Creo que eso se solucionaba con async/await, pero no sabria decirte más. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes reasignar la variable a otra distinta, para que mantenga su valor y no se sobreescriba con el ciclo.

```js
const response5 = [1,2,3];
for(i=0; i<response5.length; i++){ //el length en este caso es 3
        console.log("afuera", i);//muestra 1,2,3
        //AQUI: reasigna i a otra variable local para que no se sobreescriba en la siguiente iteración
        let otra = i;
        $.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+(i+1),function(response6){
            console.log("i", i);//muestra siempre 3
            console.log("otra", otra);/// muestra 1,2,3
            //En este código interno usas "otra" en vez de "i"
            //Hay que tener en cuenta que esta funcion puede no ejecutarse en orden secuencial
        })
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias a #masterguru por su aporte que me llevo a la solucion utilizando async/await, aqui esta como lo utilice y dio el resultado esperado

```
$("#notas_materia").change(function(event){
                n_materia=event.target.value
                $("#tablanotas").show();
                $.get("/secretaria/notas/prealumnos/"+n_periodo+"/"+n_jornada+"/"+n_modalidad+"/"+n_curso+"/"+n_seccion+"/"+n_materia+"",async function(response5){
                    for(i=0; i<response5.length; i++){ //el length en este caso es 3
                        console.log("i"+i);//muestra 1,2,3
                        let n = $.get("/docentes/notas/"+n_periodo+"/"+n_jornada+"/"+n_modalidad+"/"+n_curso+"/"+n_seccion+"/"+n_materia+"/"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"",function(response6){
                            if(response6){
                                $("#tcuerpo").append("<tr><td class='idAlumno'>"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"</td><td class='alumno'>"
                                +response5[i]['alumnos'][0].nombres+" "+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].apellidos+"</td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_a+"'></td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_e+"'></td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='"+response6.nota_t+"'></td></tr>");
                            }else{
                                $("#tcuerpo").append("<tr><td class='idAlumno'>"+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].id+"</td><td class='alumno'>"
                                +response5[i]['alumnos'][0].nombres+" "+response5[i]['alumnos'][0].apellidos+"</td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td>"
                                +"<td><input type='number' class='form-control' value='0'></td></tr>");
                            }
                            console.log(i);
                        });
                        await n;
                    }
                });
        });
```